# JavaScript: display div on index.php

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**Information:**

I have a site that has a design on index.php, and then you browse other pages(video.php, news.php) inside a frame on index.php.

**What i want to do:**

After a action(inserted to mysql.query) has happend inside the frame(video.php), i want to show a #box that is on index.php. How should i do this? And is it possible to do like echo 1; in video.php, then make a script that "if i get 1, then display #box on index.php" ? How should i do it..

I am using jquery too, for your records...

**Short:**
When you inserted a comment to the database it echo 1; (or tells the script to show #box) on index.php, which is a div that show a message like stackoverflow at the top.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "iframe" pages can contain scripts that reference other Javascript code stored in the parent window. So if you had a page that shows up in the frame, it can display a message by doing something like this:

```
<script>
  window.parent.showMessage("Video not found");
</script>
```

In the outer (parent) page, the code to show the messages would look like ordinary jQuery code. Thus your "showMessage" routine might look like:

```
function showMessage(msg) {
  $('#msgBox').text(msg).show();
}
```